# TaskschedulerR doesn´t start script.R in RGui

Tags: r, scheduled-tasks

**My general Objective:**

Load values from websites and store these values in lists by using `R.` Starting an R-script manually works and saves the corresponding values in .txt files (so, basically the workflow works like expected). Unfortunately, an automation attempt with `taskscheduleR` did not work as desired.

I'm just getting started with R (I'm aware that my code contains unnecessary sections and i will refactor the code after the workflow is fully working).

```
# ------------------- NECESSARY PACKAGES -----------------------

install.packages("lubridate")
install.packages("rvest")
install.packages("XML")
install.packages("xml2")
install.packages("httr")
install.packages("taskscheduleR")
library(xml2)
library(lubridate)
library(rvest)
library(XML)
library(httr)
library(taskscheduleR)

#----------------------------[ 1 ]-----------------------------

# define paths of subscripts

path1 <- "C:/Users/Dorian/Desktop/R/script_link_1.R"
path2 <- "C:/Users/Dorian/Desktop/R/script_link_2.R"
path3 <- "C:/Users/Dorian/Desktop/R/script_link_3.R"
path4 <- "C:/Users/Dorian/Desktop/R/script_link_4.R"
path5 <- "C:/Users/Dorian/Desktop/R/script_link_5.R"
path6 <- "C:/Users/Dorian/Desktop/R/script_link_6.R"

val1 <- source(path1)
val2 <- source(path2)
val3 <- source(path3)
val4 <- source(path4)
val5 <- source(path5)
val6 <- source(path6)

#----------------------------[ 2 ]-----------------------------

# this code opens the script and saves values to .txt files 

path_op <- "C:/Users/Dorian/Desktop/R/operations_skript.R"
op <- source(path_op)
```

Code of **operations_skript.R**:

```
list1 <- list(header = FALSE)
list2 <- list(header = FALSE)
list3 <- list(header = FALSE)
list4 <- list(header = FALSE)
list5 <- list(header = FALSE)
list6 <- list(header = FALSE)

list1 <- c()
list2 <- c()
list3 <- c()
list4 <- c()
list5 <- c()
list6 <- c()

for (i in 1:6){
if (i==1) {list1 <- c(list1, val1[1])}
if (i==2) {list2 <- c(list2, val2[1])}
if (i==3) {list3 <- c(list3, val3[1])}
if (i==4) {list4 <- c(list4, val4[1])}
if (i==5) {list5 <- c(list5, val5[1])}
if (i==6) {list6 <- c(list6, val6[1])}
}

lapply(list1, write, "bid1.txt", append=TRUE, ncolumns=1000)
lapply(list2, write, "bid2.txt", append=TRUE, ncolumns=1000)
lapply(list3, write, "bid3.txt", append=TRUE, ncolumns=1000)
lapply(list4, write, "bid4.txt", append=TRUE, ncolumns=1000)
lapply(list5, write, "bid5.txt", append=TRUE, ncolumns=1000)
lapply(list6, write, "bid6.txt", append=TRUE, ncolumns=1000)
```

Code of `script_link_1.R`: (i don´t post script_link_2:6 because, there only difference is the usage of another link to other websites)

```
link1 <- "https://www.tradegate.de/orderbuch.php?isin=CA40638K5070"     #camber

document <- htmlParse(GET(link1, user_agent("Mozilla")))
removeNodes(getNodeSet(document,"//*/comment()"))
doc.tables<-readHTMLTable(document, header=FALSE)

# Extract column from BID/ASK table
BidAsk = doc.tables[[2]][,2]

# Replace commas with point decimal separator
BidAsk = as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", BidAsk))

# Convert to numeric
BidAsk = as.numeric(BidAsk)

list1 <- list()
list1 <- c(BidAsk[1], BidAsk[2])

print(list1)
```

I wanted to automate this task with `taskscheduleR`, because I want to do this task every minute. I tried that this way:

```
#----------------------------[ 3 ]-----------------------------

# scheduledtask for automatic saving data to .txt files every minute

save_to_txt <- file.path("C:/Users/Dorian/Desktop", "R", "operations_skript.R")

taskscheduler_create(taskname = "saving", rscript = save_to_txt,
                     schedule = "MINUTE", starttime = "23:45", modifier = 1)

taskscheduler_delete(taskname = "saving") # for stopping the task
```

The problem here is that the task can be created successfully, but the script behind isn´t executed:

`[1] "ERFOLGREICH: Die geplante Aufgabe \"saving\" wurde erfolgreich erstellt."`

If I start it manually like in [ 2 ], it works as desired (stored the values in 6x .txt files).

The `taskscheduleR` only quickly opens a `cmd` for some milliseconds every minute, but doesn´t save any data. I also look at another place on my HDD, but nothing got stored.

**Do I need to unlock any permissions? Does this have anything to do with incorrect paths?**

Comment: Can you translate the error message to English? Try using absolute paths to save files or manually `setwd`. Message may indicate subfolder does not exist from working directory of automated version.

Comment: i got a message, that the task was successful created (but the task does nothing at all?). 

translated message:
[1] "SUCCESSFUL: The scheduled task \"saving\" was successfully created."

Okay, i'll try to change the paths, maybe it´s related to that issue.

Comment: Does `taskscheduleR` show errors? If there are none, text files may be saved but not in location you think.

Comment: taskscheduleR didn´t show any errors. I tried changing the paths and including setwd() in operations_skript.R, but still no .txt files are saved. If i manually start the routine ([ 2 ]), it works like a charm. I am quite confused. I also searched on my HDD, if the file got saved anywhere else, but there´s nothing at all :/

Comment: I may see what's going on. You need to automate the first code block whatever name it is *not* `operations_skript.R` which is sourced among other R scripts in first code block. Curious why there are no errors just running `operations_skript.R`. Maybe there is a logger? [Docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/taskscheduleR/versions/1.5/topics/taskscheduler_create) indicate .log file is created in same location as script.

Comment: thanks for your help, i really appreciate it. I will take a search for the logfiles today, if they exist.

Comment: I looked into operations_skript.log and found a related error: Fehler in val1 : Objekt 'val1' nicht gefunden (error in val1: Objekt 'val1' can´t be found, execution stopped). It seems, that the skript lacks some lines of code, where val1 is referenced. I´ll try to make a fix.

Comment: As I mentioned, you are automating the wrong R script. `val1` is the *first* referenced variable in `operations_skirpt.R` that comes from outside its code. You need to automate the first code block of this post which is the parent caller (i.e., runs `source` on `operations_skript.R`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you looked at the logs (for your script at `C:/Users/Dorian/Desktop/R`) and provided the full path when writing to disk?

```
lapply(list1, write, "bid1.txt", append=TRUE, ncolumns=1000)
```

should be a full path e.g.

```
lapply(list1, `write`, "C:/Users/Dorian/Desktop/bid1.txt", append=TRUE, ncolumns=1000)
```

Comment: Found a related error in the logfile of operations_skript and try to fix it actually. (error in val1: Objekt 'val1' can´t be found, execution stopped)

Answer (score 0):

The related error was, that `operations_skript.R` wasn´t able to find the path of the val1...val6 objects and it wasn´t able to use the function `readHTMLtable()` and `htmlParse()` without attaching the libraries in the second skript also.

Thank you for your help, i will look into the logfiles more often in the future.

Comment: Alternatively, save all code lines in the first block of this post in to R script and then automate that file, *not* `operations_skript.R`.